# join two tables with the max date of the filled field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where i should  get VAL from table  B by joining A and B with the max date of the  filled field, e.g:

A:

```
F1  F2  F3
--  --  --
1   2   t1
2   3   t2
```

B:

```
F1    F2    VAL  date
----  ----  ---  ----------
1     NULL  v10  12/30/2020
1     NULL  v11  01/31/2020
NULL  2     v20  02/28/2020
NULL  2     v22  03/30/2020
```

Desired result:

```
1  2  t1  v11  01/31/2020
2  3  t2  v22  03/30/2020
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure about the date values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.f1, A.f2, A.f3, 
       FIRST_VALUE(B.VAL) OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(B.f1, B.f2) ORDER BY "date" DESC) VAL,
       MAX(B."date") OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(B.f1, B.f2)) "date"
FROM A INNER JOIN B
ON A.f1 = COALESCE(B.f1, B.f2)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4d5da229ca9c3bdc8de8278e4f392382).

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.*  , maxB.* , B.VAL
from 
A
join B
   on A.f1 = B.F1 
   or A.f2 = B.F2
join 
(
   select 
   F1, F2 ,VAL , max(date) date
   from 
   B
   group by F1,F2
) maxB
on 
   B.date = maxB.date
   and (
         maxB.f1 = B.F1 
      or maxB.f2 = B.F2
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```sql
SELECT
    R.F1, R.F2, R.F3, R.VAL,R.date
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            A.F1, A.F2, A.F3,
            B.VAL,B.date, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY A.F1,A.F2,A.F3 ORDER BY B.date DESC) as Rank
        FROM A
        JOIN B ON B.F1 = A.F1 OR B.F2 = A.F1
    ) R
WHERE
    R.Rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function within the subquery

```
WITH AB AS
(
SELECT A.f1, A.f2, B.val, B."date",
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NVL(B.f1, B.f2) ORDER BY "date" DESC) AS rn
  FROM A 
  JOIN B
    ON A.f1=B.f1 OR A.f1=B.f2
)
SELECT f1,f2,val,"date"
  FROM AB
 WHERE rn = 1
```

If ties(*equal values*) for the date values is the case and all should be included within the result set, then replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `DENSE_RANK()` function.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=22d45026e046fbb7eb106eede02b47d8)</kbd>